# UITextView href link not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

This is the text to be displayed :

```
© Gregory A. Dunbar <a href=\"http://gregoryadunbar.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">gregoryadunbar.com</a>\n
```

This is the code I am using to display UITextView and trigger link :

Here **p.caption** is the above string

```
textViewCaption = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: labelPadding, y: 0.0, width: self.bounds.size.width - labelPadding * 2.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        textViewCaption.delegate = self
        textViewCaption.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        textViewCaption.isOpaque = false
        textViewCaption.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        textViewCaption.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        textViewCaption.textColor = UIColor.white
        textViewCaption.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        textViewCaption.isEditable = false
        textViewCaption.isSelectable = true
        textViewCaption.dataDetectorTypes = .link

        if let p = media  {
            let htmlData = NSString(string:String(format: "<HTML><body><font size='4'>%@</font></body></HTML>", p.caption)).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)

            let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            textViewCaption.attributedText = attributedString
        }

        self.addSubview(textViewCaption)
```

This is the delegate call to check the link :

```
public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL)
            }

        return true
    }
```

**Note : All this is in a custom view.**

This is the response :

[image]

So I have two issues here :

> 1. Text not shown completely.
> 2. Link not clickable.

Comment: Could you print `textViewCaption.attributedText`? I'd say you don't see the start of it, because the text is black by default, and so is your background color. That should explain the "not shown completely". Is the delegate method called ? You do `self.addSubview(textViewCaption) `, what is `self`? User interaction on self are enabled? Could you check the view hierarchy (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) Is there any subview above it blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links with `http` instead of `https` are blocked by default. You need to add an exception in your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>gregoryadunbar.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

or allow all unsecure links

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Also, there's much easier way to add clickable links to attributed string, instead of constructing a `HTML` document you can do

```
let text = "your full string including link gregoryadunbar.com"
let range = text.range(of: "gregoryadunbar.com")

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
attributedText.addAttribute(.link, value: "http://gregoryadunbar.com", range: range)
attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: someFont, range: Range(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))
attributedText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white range: Range(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))
```

if you don't set `UITextView`'s delegate, this should work by default

If your links are wrapped in `a href` tag, you can strip all the `HTML` tags in your link like so:

```
let link = "A. Dunbar <a href=\"http://gregoryadunbar.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">gregoryadunbar.com</a>\n"
let linkWithoutHtmlTags = link.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil) // gregoryadunbar.com
```

Comment: Just two points here : 1) I think this won't detect ahref tag 2) Text is dynamic

Comment: @Nitish 1. won't detect `a href` tag, because that way this tag is unnecessary, any `HTML` tags are unnecessary 2. text can be dynamic, `range(of: )` will find the range of link in your text

Comment: In my case, links are always coming as a href.